# Autotouch tap position between x,y

Tags: lua, autotouch

I am trying to set up a script on my iphone using autotouch and have gotten it into a workable state but am wondering whether I can use the tap xy function to press between a given range so that it's not always pressing the exact same pixel but instead has some randomness to it within the given range to avoid easy detection.
I have noticed the getColor function can search within a range but can the tap function produce a press within a range also?

Any tips for optimizing the code would also be welcomed as I'm very basic.

```
S1 = getColor(19, 667);

S2 = getColor(335, 465);

S3 = getColor(440, 342);

S4 = getColor(377, 234);

S5 = getColor(310, 206);

S6 = getColor(307, 289);

S7 = getColor(454, 360);

S8 = getColor(215, 665);



if S1 == 16763648 then

tap(266, 892);

elseif S2 == 16221852 then

tap(50, 666);

elseif S3 == 8719371 then

tap(345, 656);

elseif S4 == 11042070 then

tap(82, 669);

elseif S5 == 3530726 then

tap(377, 654);

elseif S6 == 10921638 then

tap(712, 37);

elseif S7 == 8719371 then

tap(321, 471);

elseif S8 == 8870034 then

tap(59, 662);



end
```

With some help from my brother we were able to get a random function working,
So I'm going to leave the updated code here for anyone who might be curious. :)

```
function rndtap(x,y)
x = math.random(x-10,x+10);
y = math.random(y-10,y+10);
tap(x, y);

end

if getColor(19, 667) == 16763648 then
rndtap(266, 892);

elseif getColor(335, 465) == 16221852 then
rndtap(50, 666);

elseif getColor(440, 342) == 8719371 then
rndtap(345, 656);

elseif getColor(377, 234) == 11042070 then
rndtap(82, 669);

elseif getColor(310, 206) == 3530726 then
rndtap(377, 654);

elseif getColor(307, 289) == 10921638 then
rndtap(712, 37);

elseif getColor(454, 360) == 8719371 then
rndtap(321, 471);

elseif getColor(215, 665) == 8870034 then
rndtap(59, 662);

end
```

Any further improvement suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: What programming environment are you using (corona, gideros, etc.) ?

Comment: Nothing sorry, just using a text editor from my phone and running the script through AutoTouch on ios.
Picking up information from this https://docs.autotouch.net/

Edit: if this is too "my first code" feel free to ignore and i'll see if i can close this off. xD Just thought id ask.